# Creating Custom Activity in Journey Builder using C#

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to create ET - JB custom activity. My preferred technology is .Net and language is C#. I reviewed KBs and documents however didn’t find any helpful resource which can walk me through the steps. The one I found is created for node.js/PostMonger
https://github.com/ExactTarget/journey-builder-custom-hello-world

I tried creating hello world in .net however neither the custom activity nor the custom trigger appeared in journey Builder canvas.

> cr.globalpueblo.com/Ap_JBComponent/activities/hello-world/
>
> cr.globalpueblo.com/Ap_JBComponent/activities/hello-world/config.js
>
> cr.globalpueblo.com/Ap_JBComponent/triggers/hello-world/
>
> cr.globalpueblo.com/Ap_JBComponent/triggers/hello-world/config.json

It seems that we are forced to use Node.js/ PostMonger in order to create custom activity and custom trigger for Journey Builder.

Please help and suggest if there is a way we can create JB Custom Activity and trigger using .Net and C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe using Postmonger is required; it's just a solution for nodejs custom activities.  Your c# app will just need to emulate postmonger [functionality](https://github.com/kevinparkerson/postmonger/blob/master/postmonger.js).